# .NET Core SocketIO - Cannot access disposed object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I use SocketIOClientDotNet to get data from a stream (https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet), i then want to save this data to the database;

```
private readonly DataContext _context;

public SocketIo(DataContext context)
{
    this._context = context;
}

public void SocketStart()
{
    var socket = IO.Socket("myip");

    socket.On("xx", async (data) =>
        {                                                              
            var test = await Update(data.ToString());
        });
}

public async Task<SocketPrice> Update(string data)
{
    SocketPrice socketStream = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocketPrice>(data);

    SocketPrice socketDB = await _context.SocketPrices.Where(s => s.Id == socketStream.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    socketDB.value = socketStream.value;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();   

    return socketDB;
}
```

When running this from startup;

In configure services; `services.AddScoped<ISocketIoService, SocketIo>();`

And in configure; `socket.SocketStart();`

I get the error message;

> Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a
>   disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context
>   that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to
>   use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may
>   occur if you are calling Dispose() on the con text, or wrapping the
>   context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection,
>   you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposi
>   ng context instances.

When changing the method to synchronous, the method runs but is restarted before it is finished and therefore the results are not saved to the Database. How could i change this setup to  save the new incoming data to the database?

Comment: Did you use the debugger to find out which variable has been disposed?

Answer (score 0):

Inject `IServiceProvider`. Resolve the `DataContext` when you need it.

Comment: this results in; A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.

Comment: I'd not ever suggest a DbContext to be a Singleton